# load a new dependency in slime?

Tags: clojure, swank-clojure

I am using emacs and swank-clojure. How do I resolve the below scenario -

1. I have added a new dependency to project.clj.
2. I run lein deps in a shell to get the new dep.
3. I have an existing slime session that is open and want to use a function from the new dep.

How do I get the existing slime session to load the new dependency ?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have a look at [pomegranate](https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate) which is designed to provide similar if not identical capabilities as the one you describe.

As pointed out by [@gergek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216798/georgek) in the comments, `leiningen2` ships with `pomegranate`, so that if you're on lein2 you have to just fire something like the following in the slime REPL:

```
(require '[cemerick.pomegranate :as p])
(p/add-dependencies :coordinates '[[org.clojure/core.logic "0.7.5"]])
```

Have a look at [`add-dependencies` docs](https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate/blob/master/src/main/clojure/cemerick/pomegranate.clj#L85) for more info on how to use it.

Comment: According to its readme "Pomegranate is being used by Leiningen v2.x as its sole dependency resolution library". If murtaza52 upgrades to lein 2 he should be most of the way there?

Comment: Somehow this does not work on my lein 2.5, I get this after entering the first line in a repl: FileNotFoundException Could not locate cemerick/pomegranate__init.class or cemerick/pomegranate.clj on classpath.  clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:449)