# How can new clojure libraries be loaded in the repl

Tags: clojure

So I have this workflow problem:

I'm happily typing away on my clojure project repl and realise that i need another library that is not in my `project.clj`, say in this case, i needed the `tools.cli` library.

I open up `project.clj` in my editor and add in an entry to the `:dependencies`

```
     [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.2.1"]
```

Then, within the project directory, I type `lein deps` in the shell to pull in the necessary libraries

After the project dependencies are pulled, technically all the class files are already there ready to be loaded, but if I go back to my repl and type:

```
> (use 'tools.cli)
```

I get this:

```
=>> FileNotFoundException Could not locate tools/cli__init.class
  or tools/cli.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:432)
```

So I would have to restart my repl, wasting a whole heap of time reconfiguring the state of the repl to where I was before I needed the library.

Is there a way to just load in the library dynamically? eg, after I run `lein deps` I just go back to the repl and type:

```
> (load-library "tools.cli") 
> (use 'tools.cli)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327624/load-a-new-dependency-in-slime/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pomegranate is for you:

https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate

It supports download and addition of new dependencies at runtime, e.g.:

```
(add-dependencies :coordinates '[[incanter "1.2.3"]]
                  :repositories (merge cemerick.pomegranate.aether/maven-central
                                       {"clojars" "http://clojars.org/repo"}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Will something like this work for you?

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/AJXqbpGMQw4/0-7-3pXRwGkJ

There is also clojure.core/add-classpath, but it's deprecated.

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/add-classpath

Answer (score 1):

You can try out one library in the repl using [`lein-try`](https://github.com/rkneufeld/lein-try).

`~/.lein/profiles.clj`:

`{:user {:plugins [[lein-try "0.4.3"]]}}`

`command line`:

```
$ lein try clj-time "0.5.1"
Fetching dependencies... (takes a while the first time)
lein-try loaded [clj-time "0.5.1"]

nREPL server started on port 57036
REPL-y 0.2.0
Clojure 1.5.1
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)

user=>
```