# how to automatically load new dependencies from project.clj in swank

Tags: clojure, swank, swank-clojure

I am working in emacs, swank-clojure. I start my repl using clojure-jack-in. However when I add a new dependency to my project.clj, the dependency is not available in the repl.

1) Is there a way to load new dependencies automatically in swank, when project.clj changes ?

2) Also what is a clean way to terminate the swank server ? Currently I just kill the buffer.

Thanks,
Murtaza

Comment: You have asked and had answered (1) before at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327624/load-a-new-dependency-in-slime/

Comment: Thanks @georgek, I had slipped from my mind !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Java VM starts it reads all the included jars there is straight-forward way to include jars later. If you really don't want to restart application you could try [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194698/how-to-load-a-jar-file-at-runtime). But it may get very tricky as if you don't use same class loader as Clojure does then when loading another Clojure library you may end up with 2 instances of Clojure core.

To disconnect from swank server use M-x slime-disconnect. To stop publishing on the server you can issue:

```
(swank.swank/stop-server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When should slime-disconnect be used ? What is its utility?

Comment: It simply disconnects emacs from your application, you can always reconnect with slime-connect (depends on your emacs configuration).

Comment: So stop-server, and then clojure-jack-in will reload the deps in the JVM ?

Comment: Why yes, this should do it :)

Comment: Thanks again. stop-server is not a function that is avalaible by M-x stop-server, do I need to define the above form (swank.swank/stop-server) as a function in my .emacs file ?

Comment: Let me correct myself, as far as I understand clojure-jack-in launches new instance of the application. To get rid of the old instance you're better off executing (System/exit 0). Just switch to slime-repl buffer and execute this expression.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16536/discussion-between-ivan-and-murtaza52)

Comment: The answer provided in chat is that write (System/exit 0) in the slime repl, this will send a shutdown message to the JVM. This will shutdown both the JVM and swank (which is connection to the JVM). Now doing clojure-jack-in will again load a new JVM.